# Replace a variety of placeholders in text unless part of an <a> tag's href value

Tags: php, regex, dom, pcre, google-translate

I will send texts to google translate but in the strings, there are variables that can't be translated.

So I have to add suffix and prefix to them.

But do nothing if they are within the URL of an anchor href.

The possible format of the variable is:

```
@foo !bar %foobar {foobar} {foo}.bar !bar_baz %foo-baz
```

Source:

```
> Hello Bob @foo <a href="/someurl/!foobar/!bar/word"> Word {foobar} </a> %foo someword !bar_baz
```

Expected result

```
> Hello Bob <span class="notranslate">@foo<\span> <a href="/someurl/!foobar/!bar/word"­> Word <span class="notranslate">{foobar}<\span> </a> <span class="notranslate">%foo<\span> someword <span class="notranslate">!bar_baz<\span>
```

I have made a very ugly regex that matches the variables and add suffix and prefix

```
function PregAddprefixSuffix($text){
      $pregpattern = '/(?<!href=\\")\{[a-zA-Z_0-9]+\}(\.\w+)?|(?<!href=\\")\%[a-zA-Z_0-9\-\w]+|(?<!href=\\")\@[a-zA-Z_0-9\-\w]+|(?<!href=\\")\#[a-zA-Z_0-9\-\w]+|(?<!href=\\")\![a-zA-Z_0-9\-\w]+/';
      $prefix = '<span class="notranslate">';
      $suffix = '</span>';
$result= preg_filter($pregpattern, $prefix.'$0'.$suffix, $text); }
```

I have read about the negative backreference to try to filter out matches within. but there is shortcomming aut backtracking -13 chars if i understand it Below the Regx patterns and functions I tried and their shortcomming.

### Method 1:

```
 $p ='/(?<!href=\\")\{[a-zA-Z_0-9]+\}(\.\w+)?|(?<!href=\\")\%[a-zA-Z_0-9\-\w]+|(?<!href=\\")\@[a-zA-Z_0-9\-\w]+|(?<!href=\\")\#[a-zA-Z_0-9\-\w]+|(?<!href=\\")\![a-zA-Z_0-9\-\w]+/';
 preg_filter($p, $prefix.'$0'.$suffix, $text);
```

Very ugly it match !foobar and should not in href="/someurl/**!foobar**/word"
**Pro:**

1. It match !*,%*,@*,{*} and {*}.*
2. Works with preg_filter($p, $prefix.'$0'.$suffix, $text);
3. It renders the output with the unmatched parts of our search and replace  modifications.

**Con:**

1. Very Very ugly,
2. Add prefix and suffix within href which completely break html
   semantic.

### Method 2:

https://www.phpliveregex.com/p/uNB

```
$p = '/(?:<a.*?\\">)|([\@|\!|\#|\%|\{][a-zA-Z_0-9\-\w]*[\}]?([\}]?[\.][\w]*)?)/';
preg_match_all($p, $input_lines, $output_array)
 print_r($output_array);
```

This is looking promising it match all including href in Group 1, but then  Match only the variables we want outside of Pro:

1. Group 0 matches first half of anchors (the part containing href) and so !*,%*,@*,{*} and {*}.*
2. Group 1 match exactly what we want to be prefixing and suffixing

**Con:**

1. it look like This solution does not work with preg_filter, that carried over the input string to the changed output string with the modifications.
   ...

   ### Current solution proposal.
2. How to go from having The group 2 array and having a modified matched string.
3. Probably using PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE. with a mix of offset + strlen and taking into account the offset of the match, and length(prefix.$match.suffix).
4. Make a function that move backward in the array taking the offset of the last match, then insert it in place, then go back to the previous matchs, insert de modification at that offset, and trasverse the array this Way.

It is said to be preferable to use dom in order to manipulate HTML, I'm not against it.
But then how do I Find the multiple wildcard Variables ex: `'![a-zA-Z_0-9\-\w]+'` And then add suffix prefix to the matched strings found and not to be matching within href?

I'm using https://github.com/scotteh/php-dom-wrapper in order to strip the span Element from the responses

```
function fixspan($text) {
$doc = new \DOMWrap\Document();
$doc->html($text);
$nodesem = $doc->find('em.notranslate')->contents()->unwrap();
$nodesspan = $doc->find('span.notranslate')->contents()->unwrap();
return $doc->find('body > p')->contents();  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try this:

```
<a href[^>]*(?:(?:@|!|%|#)\w+|\{\w+\})[^>]*>\K|((?:@|!|%|#)\w+|\{\w+\})
```

**Explanation:**

I have used \K to negate previous match, so didn't need to bother for negative look behind. However \K matches an empty cursor. For that I have provided an alternative solution. You get that in the php source.

[Regex 101 Sample](https://regex101.com/r/yrZYZO/2)

php source [run it](https://ideone.com/yACpjM):

```
$re = '/<a href[^>]*(?:(?:@|!|%|#)\w+|\{\w+\})[^>]*>\K|((?:@|!|%|#)\w+|\{\w+\})/m';
$str = 'Hello Bob @foo <a href="/someurl/!foobar/!bar">Word {foobar} </a> #foo someword #bar
<a href="/abc/d>koramamam</a>';
$subst = '<span class="notranslate">$1<\\\\span>';

$result = preg_replace('/<span class="notranslate"><\\\\span>/m',"",preg_replace($re, $subst, $str));

echo $result;
```

Comment: thank you i made it work, when ill get time, ill post the solution a came out with from your answer.

Comment: @GuruJR that is what I have tried to provide with this solution - the alternative.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to use regex, then simply match and discard the opening `<a>` tags before identifying the replaceable substrings.

I find the temporary tagging with "no translate" to smell of an XY Problem. If I better understood your real task and the variability of your input, I might advise the use of a DOM parser.  In lieu of deeper context, I'll assume that you want to make dynamic replacements. [Demo](https://3v4l.org/DsX4N)

```
$pattern = <<<REGEX
/
(?|
  <a .+?>(*SKIP)(*FAIL)
  |
  @([a-z]+)
  |
  !([a-z]+(?:_[a-z]+)*)
  |
  %([a-z]+(?:-[a-z]+)*)
  |
  \{([a-z]+)}(\.[a-z]+)?
)
/sx
REGEX;

$lookup = [
    'foo' => 'oof',
    'bar' => 'sand',
    'foobar' => 'FUBAR',
    'foo.bar' => 'nuts',
    'bar_baz' => 'boo',
    'foo-baz' => 'tubas',
];

$input = 'Hello Bob @foo <a href="/someurl/!foobar/!bar/word"> Word {foobar} </a> %foo someword !bar_baz';

echo preg_replace_callback(
         $pattern,
         fn($m) => $lookup[implode(array_slice($m, 1))] ?? $m[0],
         $input
     );
```

---

If I am going to strictly solve the posted question, this `preg_replace()` call will do. [Demo](https://3v4l.org/I2MbJ)

```
$pattern = <<<REGEX
/
(?:
  <a .+?>(*SKIP)(*FAIL)
  |
  @[a-z]+
  |
  ![a-z]+(?:_[a-z]+)*
  |
  %[a-z]+(?:-[a-z]+)*
  |
  \{[a-z]+}(?:\.[a-z]+)?
)
/sx
REGEX;

$input = 'Hello Bob @foo <a href="/someurl/!foobar/!bar/word"> Word {foobar} </a> %foo someword !bar_baz';

echo preg_replace(
         $pattern,
         '<span class="notranslate">$0<\span>',
         $input
     );
```